# Spring Value annotation default as expression?

Tags: java, spring

Consider the following properties in a `file`

```
defaultProperty="default"
overrideProperty="override"
```

I have a class that first need to check if `overrideProperty` is available and use it, else fallback on `defaultProperty`.

I tried doing this as

```
MyClass {

 @Value("${overrideProperty: defaultProperty}")
 String tokenizationAlgorithm;
}
```

This does not work, because what I get back is `defaultProperty` and **not** `default`(which is the value)

How can I put an expression in the default value part of `@Value` annotation?

Comment: Did you try `@Value("${overrideProperty: ${defaultProperty}}")`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following syntax:

```
@Value("${overrideProperty:${defaultProperty}}")
```

The `${overrideProperty:${defaultProperty}}` will be passed to [`PropertyPlaceholderHelper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/PropertyPlaceholderHelper.html)'s [`replacePlaceholders`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java#L126) method which would replace all placeholders of format `${name}` with their corresponding value.

Please note that due to recursive nature of [`parseStringValue`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java#L129) method, `${defaultProperty}` value will be resolved before `${overrideProperty}`. So you should always have a default value available, even in cases that the `${overrideProperty}` is provided. Also, you can provide a default value for your default value!

```
@Value("${overrideProperty:${defaultProperty:literallyDefault}}")
```

Also, *Mind the Gap*:

```
@Value("${overrideProperty: defaultProperty}")
                           ^ This space will be placed before your default value
```

Comment: space before default value is not mandatory, its working too without space

Comment: @sanjeevjha I know it's not mandatory but it will prepend an unwanted space before the actual value, e.g. "something" would turn into " something".